# GRE Tunnel Collapsing in One Direction

Tags: linux-networking, tunneling, gre

This is a related question to [another thread I posted](https://serverfault.com/questions/663259/port-forwarding-through-a-gre-tunnel).

I'm having an issue where my GRE tunnel is collapsing in one direction, but can be reopened by ping the other server using the GRE Interface.

I'm aware that Cisco routers using keepalive packets to keep the tunnel open, but I'm rather confused why it's collapsing in one direction only, any thoughts?

Comment: We need more details, what are you seeing that makes you think the tunnel collapsed.

Comment: I have a GRE tunnel going between our VPS and Dedicated Server. If there is no traffic going through the tunnel for about a minute, the VPS can no longer connect to the Dedicated Server via the tunnel. 

The only way I've found to reestablish the tunnel is to send a packet (ping) to the VPS from the Dedicated Server.